# Unable to insert record into SQLite Database from Firebase Message Service when app is in background or closed state

Tags: android, firebase, android-sqlite, firebase-notifications

I am trying out Firebase Notifications. I was able to get the Notification to work properly using [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)  documentation. The message was received and I was able to send a notification to the Notification Bar from within the `MyFirebaseMessagingService` service class. This happens even when the app is in background or closed.

What I need is to collect the data sent in the notification and insert it into an SQLite database. The code I wrote works fine if the app is in foreground, but it does not work if it is closed or in background. Here is what I wrote for the insert.

```
DbHelper dbh=new DbHelper(this,"sample.sqlite",null,1);
SQLiteDatabase sdb=dbh.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
cv.put("id","1");
cv.put("name","testname");
sdb.insert("test",null,cv);
sdb.close();
dbh.close();
```

Appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.i("Tag","inside message" );
        Log.i(StaticInfo.INFO, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.i(StaticInfo.INFO, "Notification Message Title  : " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        Log.i(StaticInfo.INFO, "Notification Message Body   : " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        insertPromotion();
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    private void insertPromotion() 
    {
        DbHelper dbh = new DbHelper(this, "sample.sqlite", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase sdb = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put("id","1");
        cv.put("name","testname");
        sdb.insert("test", null, cv);
        sdb.close();
        dbh.close();

        Log.i("Tag","db closed");
    }

}
```

Comment: If this works when the app is foreground, your insert code works perfectly. Check whether it is getting executed if the app is in background. May be check your service is running when the app is in background.

Comment: @SamuelRobert i checked , it dosent work from background either.Also LogCat is disconnected when app goes to background. But i am sure the Service works as Notification is still displayed in either case.

Comment: Post the manifest declaration of the service

Comment: @SamuelRobert i have updated my question with the Manifest entries for the Services i used.

Comment: Can you post MyFirebaseMessagingService class code? Your manifest looks okay

Comment: @SamuelRobert I have added the MyFirebaseMessagingService code.

Comment: same issue...please answer if someone knows

Comment: @DäñishShärmà If you r still looking for a solution , the answer is , if the app is in background and the FCM contains message property it never goes into the onMessageReceived , the notification is sent by the system. So to send data in such a case we need to use a server side script to send FCM with only 'to' & 'data'  parameters. This will always reach the service.

Comment: i didn't understand which service you are talking about. Can you please post the code how to insert data into local database when app is in background ? Actually i'm creating chatting application and if app is in foreground everything is fine, it is hitting the onMessageReceived() but i'm getting problem in backround same like you.

Comment: @DäñishShärmà There is no change in the Table insertion code. Its just that the onMessageReceived of the FirebaseMessagingService is never called if the sent data contains 'notification' element and app is closed or in background. For the required data format you can look at the choosen answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notifications will be delivered to your app's `onMessageReceived` only when the app is in the foreground. When your app is backgrounded or not running, the system will handle the notification and display it in the system tray.

The [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) explains it as:

> **Notification message** - FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app. Notification messages have a predefined set of user-visible keys.
>
> **Data message** - Client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages have only custom key-value pairs.

Since you want your code to always be invoked, you'll need to send data messages. You cannot send data messages from the Firebase Console. But if you already send messages from an app server, the process for sending data messages and notification messages is the same there. The only difference is in the JSON structure, where a data messages doesn't have a `notification` object. From the [documentation on data messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages)

```
{
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
     "Nick" : "Mario",
     "body" : "great match!",
     "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
   },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip i was able to fix the problem with your suggestion

Comment: You saved my day. I had in my json both: "notification" and "data" objects. Removed my "notification" object and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To save data received on onMessgeReceived() to SQLite database even when your app is in the background (no activity running), you can do the following:

1) Create a class that extends IntentService, e.g:

```
public class SQLService extends IntentService {
    private final static String MESSAGE_ID = "message_id";

    private MySQLiteDbAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;

    public SQLService() {
        super("test-service");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // initialize SQLite adapter here using getApplicationContext()
        this.mySQLiteAdapter = new MySQLiteDbAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // fetch data to save from intent
        Message message = new Message();
        Message.setMessage_id(intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_ID));
        ...
        // save 
        this.mySQLiteAdapter.add(message);

    }
}
```

2) Launch the service class from onMessageReceived() method or a method within your extension of the Firebase service, e.g.:

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        if (remoteMessage.getData() != null) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SQLService.class);
            // add data to intent
            intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_ID, remoteMessage.getData().get(MESSAGE_ID));
            ...
            // start the service
            startService(intent);

        }
    }
```

3) Register the service in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
  ...
        <service
            android:name=".SQLService"
            android:exported="false"/>
  ...
```

For more in-depth explanation see https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services